# AppleScript unable to get text from safari

Tags: applescript, safari, javascript

I'm setting a text in a safari textfield with this code :

```
set myCaseNote to "demo"

tell application "Safari Technology Preview"
    set setData to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('text-entry')[1].value=" & quoted form of myCaseNote in document 1
end tell
```

but I want to add a repeat statement to make sure that my text is added before going to the next step.

I though about double check the content of the textfield with this :

```
 tell application "Safari Technology Preview"
    set DSIDinfoGrab to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('text-entry')[1].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1
end tell
```

Otherwise this don't seems to get anything

> Result: ""

Why can I not get the text from the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a user input text field, it won't have an `innerHTML` property (or, it might, but it won't contain any meaningful data) because it's an element that can't contain child HTML elements itself.

You ought to be able to read the `value` property that you use to set its text content.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('text-entry')[1].value;
```

Comment: Yes that make sense, didn't even notice that, thank you that work perfectly.